# Python - search through directory trees, rename certain files

Tags: python, recursion, subdirectory

How do I search through subdirectories in Python to find files that match a pattern? I can do this if I manually change directories and run a script, but I'd like to start at the root directory of this tree and run the script. I can't pull it off.

Here's what I do inside the directory that works like a charm:

```
for root, subs, files in os.walk("."):
    date = re.search("\w*.-\w*.-\w*.",file)
    date_clean = date.group(0).strip()
    hour = re.search("hr\d", file)
    hour_clean = hour.group(0).strip()
    new_name = "Podcast-" + date_clean + "-" + hour_clean +".mp3"
    print "Changing",file,"to",new_name+"."
    os.rename(file,new_name)
```

This works if I change to the directory and run it, but I'd like to run it from the root directory.

```
D:\Files
    \Podcasts
       \August
         \Show 1 AUG-12-2013 Portland hr 1.mp3
          Show 2 AUG-12-2013 Portland hr 2.mp3
```

Since I have files for more than one month, I'd like to rename them all
Podcast-MMM-DD-YYYY-hrX.mp3. I tried using fnmatch.filter, but that only helps me find the directories, not go in them and rename these files.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use *absolute* filenames when renaming:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, new_name))
```

You also do not appear to be looping over the `files` list; add another `for` loop:

```
for root, subs, files in os.walk("."):
    for file in files:
```

You may want to avoid using `file` as a name, it shadows the built-in type. Perhaps `filename` is a better choice?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured it out. And you're right, filename would have been better.